# What kind of rank is Supreme Leader?

Tags: star-wars

In the sequel trilogy of Star Wars, I have heard *Supreme Leader* word enough. Supreme Leader Snoke seemed at the top of command, but I encountered Assaj Ventress being referred to as Supreme Leader during Clone Wars era:

(jump to 00:48)

While terminologies of ranks can be different for different governments, in this case, everything is connected. Supreme Leader Snoke was part of remnants of the Galactic Empire which was governed by Sith.

Is Supreme Leader a formal rank? Or, could it be used informally for anyone leading a local mission?

Is there anything in the canon which explains Supreme Leader rank in the sequel trilogy?

Comment: “I encountered Assaj Ventress being referred to as Supreme Leader” — is there any chance that [Diana Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supremes) was voicing her at the time?

Comment: No leader is more supreme.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Ventress, [Supreme Leader](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Supreme_Leader_(Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems)) was a Separatist military title exclusive to her. Presumably, since Dooku was the de-facto political leader of the Separatists, Ventress as his right hand was the de-facto overall military leader. However, since her title only appears in a single episode, ["Ambush"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ambush), which was the first episode aired (though not the first produced) and it's not referenced in *any* other episode of the show or, as far as I'm aware, any other Canon or Legends material related to the Clone Wars, it may simply have been a title she gave herself to express her high ranking in the CIS.

Snoke's (and subsequently Kylo Ren's) use of the title [Supreme Leader](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Supreme_Leader) is a doubly political and military role similar to how assorted totalitarian governments in the real world have used the title for their head of state. Compare this to the real-world use of "Supreme Leader" for North Korea's head of state (currently Kim Jong-un), *der Fuehrer* ("the leader" or "the guide") for Adolf Hitler, *Il Duce* ("the leader") for Benito Mussolini, *Vozhd* ("leader" or "guide") for Josef Stalin, and the rank of "Supreme Leader" in Iran. Unlike Ventress, who was solely a military leader and an assassin/agent of Count Dooku, Snoke and Ren are both political and military leaders of the First Order and their affectation of "Supreme" indicates that no other entity in their regime can outrank them.